# Как правильно сделать xor шифратор на Java?

Tags: java, xor

Написан код для шифрования методом xor, но появилась проблемка, при работе кода какой бы текст и код я не вводил всегда выводится как результат шифрования это [B@1f17ae12

`Введите текст
ASDFGvcx
Введите код
xxx
[B@1f17ae12`

Вот кусок кода отвечающий за кодирование

```
byte[] txt = text.getBytes();
byte[] key = pass.getBytes();
byte[] res = new byte[txt.length];
for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)``
    {
res[i] = (byte) (txt[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
    }
return res;
```

Comment: Не понтяно при каких разных вводах у вас какой одинаковый результат

Comment: Какой бы текст и код я не вводил всегда выводится как результат шифрования это [B@1f17ae12

Comment: неправильно массив выводите `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));`

Comment: @IR42, спасибо, помогло